# Golang: html pages and GO communication

Tags: javascript, html, go

Is there a way other than templates to communicate between Go and html pages ? Using something like postmessages ?

Scenario ::--> Streaming Twitter Api

Streaming api call, updates with new content as and when available;

Want to update the web page with the latest content, keeping the original content as it is.

Want to avoid using NaCl... As it is only for chrome

Comment: Have a look at this [websocket library for Go](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/websocket).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use websockets ([WebSocket@Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)).

Here are 2 implementations:

[**`golang.org/x/net/websocket`**](http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/websocket)

[**`github.com/gorilla/websocket`**](http://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket)

And here is an exhausting list of other websocket packages/implementations:

[**godoc.org websocket search**](http://godoc.org/?q=websocket)

Answer (score 1):

Use [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or [server sent events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) to push events from the server to the browser client.

Use the [gorilla/websocket](http://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket) package for websockets. The [x/net/websocket](http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/websocket) package is also available, but it's partial implementation of the protocol [does not work with recent versions of Chrome](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/7632).

Server sent events are so simple that a helper package is not really needed. See [this example](https://github.com/kljensen/golang-html5-sse-example) to get started with server sent events.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about Go. Client side i.e. browser must be capable to handle persistent connection. So nothing new here. You have

- Long-polling for older browsers
- Websockets for modern browsers
- Server-sent-events for tomorrow (to say, excluding IE, them holds even
  now)
- Push-services provided by Google and Apple for mobile platforms

Either technics can be easily implemented with Go on server side. Nothing tricky.